# React State Value Always Resets to InitialState When One Function Runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-state

I am building an application module that enables the user to drag-and-drop elements into drop containers (react-dnd) to set a specific value for the object the element represents, which is stored in an object within an array held in State.

Using console.log everywhere, I can see the DnD is successful in setting the new value. However, the next time I attempt a DnD, the entire function starts with the State value reset back to the value given to it at instantiation. I have other console.logs set up to run when the entire module re-renders, which would show if the State is being changed between DnD actions, but no such re-render occurs. I even watch the state value in the React Tools of the Developer Console, and the value here does not change until after the DnD action.

Relevant code:

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useImmer } from 'use-immer';
    
    const EnsembleProfile = (initialProps) => {
        const [ensemble, updateEnsemble] = useImmer(initialProps.ensemble);
        const [viewSchema, setViewSchema] = useState(initialProps.baseSchema)
        const [schemaAssignments, setSchemaAssignments] = useState()
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setSchemaAssignments(viewSchema.assignments)
        }, [viewSchema])
    
        const { name, membership, typeId } = ensemble;
        
        const handleDrop = async (payload) => {
            // console.log(schemaAssignments) here will show the loaded value from the useEffect above,
            // regardless of the value it held just prior to this function being triggered.

            if (!payload.value) return null;
            const { item, value } = payload;
    
            const newAssignments = [...schemaAssignments]
            if (item.assignmentId) {
                const index = newAssignments.findIndex(assignment => {
                    return `${assignment.membershipId}-${assignment.schemaId}-${assignment.divisionId}` === item.assignmentId;
                })
                if (index < 0) return null;
                newAssignments[index] = { ...newAssignments[index], assignmentId: `${item.id}-${viewSchema.id}-${value.id}`, divisionId: value.id, division: value }
                
            } else {
                newAssignments.push({ assignmentId: `${item.id}-${viewSchema.id}-${value.id}`, schemaId: viewSchema.id, membership: item, memberId: item.memberId, capacity: value.capacity, divisionId: value.id, division: value });
            }
    
            setSchemaAssignments(newAssignments);
    
        }

        ...
    }
```

As I stated, the Drag-n-Drop operation functions nominally. The "value" object contains the new divisionId value that I am trying to apply to the "item" model and store in State. The "item" object contains values from the database, as well as a constructed "assignmentId" value that is the conglomeration of the three db values comprising the composite id: membershipId + schemaId + divisionId.

On my first Drop action, Everything appears to work fine. State is updated and shows exactly the values I would expect. It's on the second Drop action where the problem arises: a console.log placed as the first action of "handleDrop" will reveal that schemaAssignments is back to the initial array value. However, this appears to be triggered somehow during the DnD action, as I also created a button I can click at will to show the value of the schemaAssignments in the console, and it remains the expected value right up until I drop a new item. Somehow, without triggering a re-render, State is reset instantly upon a Drop action. Even the useEffect does not fire (I had a test console.log in there as well).

Perhaps, however, I am doing this all wrong. I have tried a number of approaches, initially trying to use Immer to achieve the state change directly in the "viewSchema" State value before breaking it off into it's own State. Regardless of approach, every second Drop operation returns a "-1" value for index, as the assignments value is always reverted, without re-render, to the initial value supplied on instantiation.

Further confusing: If I change the "viewSchema", which triggers the useEffect and loads an entirely new assignments array into memory, this problem persists. Performing a DnD action manifests the original "schemaAssignments" array again, even though the "viewSchema" value is unchanged. Upon completing the Drop, the screen re-renders to show both the drop action I just made, as well as assignments from the old assignment array.

Just to drive myself further crazy, I wiped out the setState for schemaAssignments and initialized with an empty array. Fortunately, Drop actions this time around id NOT start with the original array, and were always empty. At least one thing worked as expected.

To sum up: everything functions as expected and all values are correct right up until "handleDrop" fires, and immediately it changes the assignments array to the initially loaded value from the database, before triggering any renders.

I've been using React for well over two years now and have never encountered anything like this. Halp!

(and lastly, all apologies for non-optimized code, I've been hammering at this for days, and this is as cleaned up as I can make it right now)

Answer (score 0):

After many, *many* more hours spent placing console.logs everywhere, I have finally discovered the problem.

As it turns out, the values sent to the Draggable item do not automatically get updated unless they themselves are re-rendered, OR it is expressed as a dependency in the useDrag hook in React-DnD. This means each time I dropped a dragged item, it was firing handleDrop with the values it was instantiated with, rather than the live state values. Putting the handleDrop function as a dependency fixed this right up, and it now calls the function with the expected values.

```
const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: cardType,
    item: membership,
    end(item, monitor) {
        const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult()
        console.log(dropResult);
        if (item && dropResult) {
            const { value } = dropResult;
            doSomething({ membership: item, division: value });
        }
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
        isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
    })
}), [dropAction])
```

It's that last "[dropAction]" that was the killer. In this case, as part of my debugging, I re-wrote my DnD functions to place the action in the dragged item, instead of the drop container, but it would have worked in either configuration, provided I supplied the dependency.